# PHP PECL extension V8Js on Openshift Online

Tags: php, openshift

I need Openshift Online to get the PHP PECL extension V8Js running for letting React.js execute server side Javascript from PHP. Are PECL extensions now enabled? If yes, how can I do that? The last I saw was a [feature request](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1054642) for this from 02.2014. But I did not get information if in the meantime something has changed.

25.07.2015: I'm a step further. Corey pointed me to a promising direction. Did not know, that PECL is some kind of PEAR. Both seem compatible to openshift. I added 'v8js' to the .openshift/pear.txt file and when git pushing the app the console talked to me. I tried to install v8js with 'pecl install channel://pecl.php.net/v8js-0.2.0' but the compiler could not find V8, console said:
checking for V8 Javascript Engine... yes, shared
checking for V8 files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the v8 distribution
So, how do I find the path to V8, and how do I know, if it is already there? If not there, how do I get it?

26.07.2015: Did not manage to install V8. I tried to do it like described in the [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/v8/build). The compilation takes 600MB! and I am running out of quota. Maybe I may need to upgrade python version too, since the depot_tools require a more recent version. So, this is very complicated right now. I am asking myself, if I am on the right track. I would still prefer the mainstream PHP way with V8Js for serverside Javascript instead of node.js.

What shall I do? another shared hosting (search hard)? Cloud hosting, like bitnami and Amazon AWS? Is there still hope with openshift? Virtual, managed server? I am confused.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to execute JS from PHP and can't do so using Node?

Comment: Yeah, N.B. now I will go the node.js route and build some rendering service and call this service from PHP. Seems to be no exotic architecture, although the requests to the PHP controllers have to make additional requests to the node server. I try to avoid to make node.js the whole platform since PHP is more widespread.

Comment: You don't have to make it the whole platform, but it's more mature when it comes to executing JS code from the server side. For example, I barely managed to compile v8js for PHP, it's a freakin' gamble to get that thing working - now imagine potential issues when it executes JS code and bugs occur. Node is definitely something that you can rely on to execute JS code. Then, you can either talk to node via REST (HTTP) or try to execute stuff from shell via `shell_exec` or similar and use PHP to send the output back to the user.

Comment: Thanks N.B. for the confirmation. Right, better some request indirection than a foreseeable chance to break. What a luck, Openshift Online has a node.js gear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Openshift Online support immediately answered my question: "Sorry, we do not have the V8Js PECL extension at this time".
But from the hints of corey112358 and N.B. and own experience and from internet research I additionally learned that it's a hassle to make that extension run or find hosting support, if you are not a Google engineer who can install v8 or if you have no time or money to run an own server or if you are no expert in V8Js. So, in this case, you may find node.js a more comfortable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading through the section of the Developer Portal about PHP cartridge dependencies? https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-getting-started.html#step3

Comment: Yeah, that's about adding PEAR dependencies, but mine is PECL. I did not find V8Js as PEAR.